# Adding ck editor to a Bolt cms site

Tags: ckeditor, bolt-cms

I have a bolt cms website. On the entries/ showcase pages I would like to replace the default editor with the CK editor.Right now the editor has only the basic buttons that is 6 -7 buttons.It looks something like this :
[image]

Whereas I want this kind of an editor:
[image]
 How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `app/config/config.yml` file you have the following section:

```
wysiwyg:
    images: false            # Allow users to insert images in the content.
    anchor: false            # Adds a button to create internal anchors to link to.
    tables: false            # Adds a button to insert and modify tables in the content.
    fontcolor: false         # Allow users to mess around with font coloring.
    align: false             # Adds buttons for 'align left', 'align right', etc.
    subsuper: false          # Adds buttons for subscript and superscript, using `<sub>` and `<sup>`.
    embed: false             # Allows the user to insert embedded video's from Youtube, Vimeo, etc.
    underline: false         # Adds a button to underline text, using the `<u>`-tag.
    ruler: false             # Adds a button to add a horizontal ruler, using the `<hr>`-tag.
    strike: false            # Adds a button to add stikethrough, using the `<s>`-tag.
    blockquote: false        # Allows the user to insert code snippets using `<pre><code>`-tags.
    codesnippet: false       # Allows the user to insert blockquotes using the `<blockquote>`-tag.
    specialchar: false       # Adds a button to insert special chars like '€' or '™'.
```

Setting these to true will give you the relevant buttons.

As for extra buttons via plugins, we'll be adding that ability natively with CKEditor 5.

Comment: I am sorry. I have updated my question now. Hope that helps!